# Is the Hessian of the strain energy of a hyperelastic material positive definite in general

Tags: optimization, matrix-factorization, nonlinear, hyperelastic

Is the spatial second derivative of the strain energy of a hyperelastic material positive definite in general?

If this is not a general property of hyperelastic materials are there techniques for approximating positive definiteness? Or are some hyperelastic material models positive definite?

I am doing some large-scale nonlinear optimization on hyperelastic materials and I want to be able to leverage fast linear solvers such as LU factorization and Cholesky decomposition both of which require positive definite systems.

**Update**

I found a text that appears to suggest that the principle of minimum potential energy corresponds to the requirement that the Hessian of the potential energy is positive definite. Is this principle applicable in this case?

[image]

Comment: Is the strain energy a convex functional? If so, then the Hessian is positive definite.

Comment: Look up the early literature on quasi-convexification.  The idea is to smooth out local maxima by using a convex hull.

Comment: LU factorization doesn't require a matrix to be positive definite.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth From Report of NRL Progress (January 1961): *In the general theory of elasticity, it has been found that the assumption that strain energy is a strictly convex function of strain leads to results which agree with observation.  It is convineint for numerous purposes to deal with the Hessian matrix of the strain energy and, and in many thermodynamic theories functions are uses whose Hessian matrices are positive definite.*

Comment: It is true that if the energy is convex, then the Hessian is positive definite. That's why I asked. The issue for you to figure out is whether for your specific material, the energy is convex. This is true for most (nonlinear) elastic formulations, but not for biphasic ones for example.

Comment: If the Hessian is pos-def, the strain energy function would be convex and there would be a unique solution for the static problem. Gurtin, in his book "Topics in finite elasticity" shows that even for a simple example like a unit cube of an incomp. Neo-Hookean matl, subjected to simple tension or comp there are multiple solutions. Since the solutions are not unique, this means that even for such a simple material the strain energy function is not convex and the Hessian is not positive definite (I hope the presence of pressure in incompressible elasticity doesn't change this conclusion).

Comment: @NNN I did a similar experiment with Neo-Hookean materials and noticed that my optimization kept failing because the model predicted negative energies. I have since switched to the St Venand Kirchoff model which AFAICS predicts only positive energies.

Comment: @NNN No, you are confusing the direction in which you can make inferences. If the Hessian is positive definite at one point, that does not imply that the energy function is convex. A counter-example is $f(x)=x^2-x^4$. Its Hessian is positive at $x=0$, $f''(0)=2$, but the function is not convex. Similarly, multiple solutions just mean that the energy is not *globally* convex, but it can be locally convex and the Hessian can be positive definite locally as well. Example: $f(x)=x^4-x^2$.

Comment: @Olumide For energies, all that matters are *energy differences*. A material with energy $E(u)$ and a material with energy functional $\tilde E(u)=E(u)+1000$ behave in exactly the same way. Negative energies are therefore completely ok.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Correct you are. I should have been more clear.